# Data annotation not displaying error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I want to use data annotations in my app and the problem is  when I click in submit button and don't fill the required field I don't see any error message and it submits. In the controller, the model.state works fine, but I think I should see the error message.

The model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ValidationTest.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter your name.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Lastname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The View:

```
@model  ValidationTest.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Record", "Home"))
    {
        @Html.Label("Name:")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        <br />
        @Html.Label("Lastname:")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Lastname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Lastname)
        <input type="submit" value="Record" />
    }
</body>
</html>
```

The controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ValidationTest.Models;

namespace ValidationTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Record(User usr)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Content("It Worked!");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

In Scripts folder inside the ASP.NET MVC project i have:

> bootstrap.js
>
> bootstrap.min.js
>
> jquery-3.2.1.intellisense.js
>
> jquery-3.2.1.js
>
> jquery-3.2.1.min.js
>
> jquery-3.2.1.min.map
>
> jquery-3.2.1.slim.js
>
> jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js
>
> jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js
>
> modernizr-2.6.2.js

Comment: jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js required for client side validation

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add JavaScript script references of `jquery.validate.min.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` for client side validation to work.

Answer (score 0):

Move return RedirectToAction("Index"); inside if (ModelState.IsValid) condition.
return view(); should be added outside if condition.